# Integrating $x \sec^2 (x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

I had a question to integrate $\int_{}^{} x \sec^{2}(x)\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x $

I converted it to $\int_{}^{} x\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\tan(x) $

Then I assumed $x = \tan^{-1}u$

So I got $\int \tan^{-1} u\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}u $
Which will give
$\frac{1}{u^2 + 1} + C$

Now, $\tan(x) = u$ , so the final answer is $\frac{1}{\tan^2(x) + 1} + C$ or simply
$\cos^2(x) + C$ which is incorrect.

Can you please point out where I went wrong

Comment: Just as well you can apply integration by parts straight away, to get $$x \tan x - \int \tan x \,dx + C$$

Comment: I want to reward @银雀Sparrxw's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have $$\frac {\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}u}\tan^{-1}u=\frac1{u^2+1},$$
not $$\int\tan^{-1}u\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}u=\frac1{u^2+1}+C.$$
To integrate $\tan^{-1}u$, you could try ways like integral by parts:
\begin{align}
\int\tan^{-1}u\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}u 
& = u\tan^{-1}u-\int u\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\left(\tan^{-1}u\right) \\
& = u\tan^{-1}u-\int\frac u{1+u^2}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}u \\
& = u\tan^{-1}u-\frac12\int\frac{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}(1+u^2)}{1+u^2} \\
& = u\tan^{-1}u-\frac12\ln(1+u^2)+C.
\end{align}
Now let's bring back your substitution $u=\tan x$:
\begin{align}
\int x\sec^2x\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x
& = \tan x\tan^{-1}(\tan x)-\frac12\ln(1+\tan^2x)+C \\
& = x\tan x-\frac12\ln(\sec^2x)+C \\
& = x\tan x-\ln|\sec x|+C \\
& = x\tan x+\ln|\cos x|+C.
\end{align}

---

In fact, we can do this trick earlier to solve this, no need to have the substitution.
\begin{align}
\int x\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\tan x
& = x\tan x-\int\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x \\
& = x\tan x+\int\frac{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}(\cos x)}{\cos x} \\
& = x\tan x+\ln|\cos x|+C.
\end{align}

---

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 12):

It turns out that $\frac1{u^2+1}$ is what you get when you *differentiate* $\arctan u$. But here you are supposed to find an antiderivative instead.

Answer (score 4):

Others have mentioned your error - that you've confused the derivative of $\tan^{-1} u$ for the integral.

While it is certainly possible to compute the integral of $\tan^{-1},$ there is an easier approach to the question.
This is a case for integration by parts.

Letting  $u=x, dv=\sec^2x\,dx$ gives $du=dx, v=\tan x.$ So the integral is:

$$uv-\int v\,du=x\tan x-\int \tan x\,dx$$

But  with $y=\cos x,$ $-\tan x\,dx = \frac{dy}y,$ so you get your integral is:

$$x\tan x+\ln|\cos x|+C$$

---

One hint for why integration by parts is a good idea here is that the mixture of $x,$ or more generally, any polynomial, with trig functions often calls for integration by parts.

In general, computing $\int xf(x)\,dx$ can be seen as the result of integrating $f$ twice. If $F''(x)=f(x),$ then $$\int xf(x)\,dx= xF'(x)-F(x).$$

Answer (score 4):

If we put $u=\tan x$, then we should have $x=\tan^{-1} u$ and $du=\sec^2 xdx$.  Therefore we get
$$
\int x \sec ^2 x d x=\int \tan ^{-1} u d u .
$$
That means we have to integrate $\tan^{-1} x$ **instead** of differentiating it.  Now we can deal with it by integration by parts as below:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int x \sec ^2 x d x & =\int \tan ^{-1} u d u \\
& =u \tan ^{-1} u-\int u \cdot \frac{1}{1+u^2} d u \\
& =u \tan ^{-1} u-\frac{1}{2} \ln \left(1+u^2\right)+C \\
& =x \tan x-\frac{1}{2} \ln \left(1+\tan ^2 x\right)+C \\
& =x \tan x-\ln |\sec x|+C \\
& =x \tan x+\ln |\cos x|+C
\end{aligned}
$$